# With springboot 1.4 a properties file is not found when jar is run from CLI

Tags: spring, jar, spring-boot

I've a simple spring-boot application that reads a conf.properties file that is stored in the same path of application.properties.

If i compile the app with spring-boot 1.3.1 everything works fine, however upgrading to spring-boot 1.4.0 showed a strange (for me) issue:

When i run the app from within my IDE (intelliJ Idea community) everything is still fine, but if i run it from command line: ./myapp.jar then i get an exception about my conf.properties file not being found.

any ideas?

Comment: The class loading [changed significantly](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes) between versions 1.3 and 1.4. Have you tried adding the current directory to the classpath?